# How would one go about creating one’s own graphics effect in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, effect

I have an `Image` object in my application which the user can drag around. The object displays an image which is partly transparent, so the window background (which is itself a bitmap) can be seen through it.

I want to add a graphics effect to this object. Assume that I already have an algorithm for this effect — that’s not the issue. The issue is how to get this algorithm into WPF.

So I tried to look at how `DropShadowEffect` works, but the implementation displayed in Reflector is empty. I also tried to look at what methods from the abstract classes `Effect` and `ShaderEffect` I should override and there doesn’t seem to be anything related to actually rendering an effect.

So how do I create my own effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best and fastest way is to use [pixel shaders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_shader) (supported starting with WPF 3.5 SP1 I think) . It will require some shader language ([HLSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Level_Shader_Language)) knowledge, though :-)

Here is a tutorial: [How Do I: Create Custom Pixel Shader Effects for WPF](http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=296117)

a library on codeplex: [Windows Presentation Foundation Pixel Shader Effects Library](http://wpffx.codeplex.com/)

an article with .NET 4 information (including Sliverlight support which has it too): [SilverShader – Introduction to Silverlight and WPF Pixel Shaders](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/SilverShader--Introduction-to-Silverlight-and-WPF-Pixel-Shaders)

Answer (score 1):

A very cool tool (and resource) is [Shazzam](http://www.shazzam-tool.com/) it will help you to create the effects and it contains a nice tutorial.