# How to set the color of a SVG image in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, svg

We receive a SVG image path from our model. This image is also used on web and winform, so we cannot use XAML.
Those are only grey-images and we need to be able to set any color for those image. I was wondering if it could be possible to add some kind of color layer that would only set the color of the non-transparent part?

here is what I've now:

```
<Window x:Class="CustomBrushesExample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:svg1="clr-namespace:SVGImage.SVG;assembly=DotNetProjects.SVGImage"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomBrushesExample" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Title="SVGImage" Height="540" Width="720" Background="Wheat" ResizeMode="NoResize" Margin="3">
            <svg1:SVGImage 
                x:Name="StartingImage" SizeType="SizeToContent"
                Source="/CustomBrushesExample;component/Images/test_3.svg" 
                Margin="20" 
                RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" 
                VerticalContentAlignment="Top" 
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Window>
```

SVGImage is the .net team implementation to show SVG images: https://github.com/dotnetprojects/SVGImage

Comment: @Sinatr it's the .Net team implementation of a viewer allowing you to see the SVG in WPF: https://github.com/dotnetprojects/SVGImage

Comment: A layer is only a background sheet and will not change image color.  Only changes what is not an image.  You want to change the image color.  Probably the images are HREF files.  SVG is XML format which is text.  So you can open the file with a viewer like notepad and see if the object you want to change colors are reference image files, or objects in the xml.

Comment: SVG files are just XML files with Path or other geometrical objects, each with their own fill/stroke, which is defining the color.

Comment: Maybe you can go with [custom effects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5770730/1997232) (shaders). Create one what will change colors. I recall I tried to make one, but had some problems with aliasing.

Comment: @jdweng Yes I know how to modify SVG, but I've to bind it to a color choosed by a color picker on runtime.

Comment: If it is an image then you have to treat it as a bitmap and change the contents of the image.

Comment: @jdweng Since it's an grey image, I was hopping to be able to just add a colored layer over it, wouldn't this be possible?

Comment: You have to change the pixels in the image.   See following : https://www.wikiwand.com/en/BMP_file_format